# UNIX text processing for a log file based on col (:)

Tags: text-processing

ACTUAL LOG_FILE:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

xyz:5:90:34:89:22:07

abbc1:6:346:78:89:100:01

ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

abbc1:6:346:78:89:100:01

SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

xyz:5:90:34:89:22:07

abbc1:6:346:78:89:100:01

v-gz1:999:39:56:23:101:123

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

v-gz1:999:39:56:23:101:123
```

Required output:

```
xyz:5:90:34:89:22:07

abbc1:6:346:78:89:100:01

abbc1:6:346:78:89:100:01

xyz:5:90:34:89:22:07

abbc1:6:346:78:89:100:01

v-gz1:999:39:56:23:101:123

v-gz1:999:39:56:23:101:123
```

what i am looking , to process logfile based on coln (:)

1. `sed '/^ :*$/d' logfile1 > logfile2` (delete line with space before :)
2. `sed '/^: *$/d' logfile2 > logfile3` (delete line with space after :)
3. delete line with no `:`

Comment: In the output, do you need exactly one blank line between each 7-field line?

Comment: (1) Example data is good. Showing the commands you’ve tried is good. But, in the future, please *explain* the pattern you are looking for. Do you care about the number of colons on the line? Do you care about colon and space being side-by-side?  (2) You say “delete line with no `:`”, but you show six blank lines in your output. So, do you want the process to show the blank lines in the input (which is not consistent with your example), or do you want to add a blank line after every line of output (or is it something else)?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v " " $IN | grep -P ":.*:"
```

Comment: for some reason the output file is empty

Comment: it is not working

Comment: @Naga stackexchange thought my *'s were formatting, so I edited the answer to make the visible... then I though grep was more simple.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your valid lines have a colon followed by a decimal digit.  They also start with a lowercase alphanumeric string, possibly including a hyphen.  So your regex is

```
^[a-z0-9-]+[0-9]
```

Your output has a blank line after every output row.  If that's what you really want, use sed:

```
sed -Ene '/^a-z0-9-]+:[0-9]/ s/$/\n/p' filename
```

If you don't need the doubled newline, the same pattern in grep is simpler.

Answer (score -1):

It's

```
<input | grep -oP '(.+?:){6}.+'
```

Here the regex https://regex101.com/r/EO1yhi/1